# Replace LED chip with reversed polarity pin-out

Tags: led, polarity

I want to upgrade the LED chips of a projector.

- Red: [PT-120-R-C11](https://www.yic-electronics.de/datasheet/fb/GR-CS8PM1.23-JUKQ-1.pdf) --> [PT‐120‐RAX‐L15](https://download.luminus.com/datasheets/Luminus_PT-120_Datasheet.pdf)
- Green: [PT-120-G-C11](https://www.yic-electronics.de/datasheet/fb/GR-CS8PM1.23-JUKQ-1.pdf) --> [PT‐120‐G‐L11](https://download.luminus.com/datasheets/Luminus_PT-120_Datasheet.pdf)
- Blue: [PT-120-B-C11](https://www.yic-electronics.de/datasheet/fb/GR-CS8PM1.23-JUKQ-1.pdf) --> [PT‐120‐B‐L11](https://download.luminus.com/datasheets/Luminus_PT-120_Datasheet.pdf)

But the red LED chip (PT‐120‐RAX‐L15) has reversed polarity pin-out.
Swapping black and red cables should solve this problem, am I right?

Do I also have to swap these cables?
[image]

Another picture:

[image]

© cine4home

Comment: You've given six links to follow so I suggest that's a bit much and going to be off-putting for most readers. Post sufficient details in your question that it can be understood without the links and so that it makes sense if the links die. It's not clear what the mechanical drawing is supposed to show.

Comment: These are two different links. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer opinion on why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, reverse the connector.

[image]
I believe it serves as a reminder to adjust the color icc profile for the projector for color correction.  (opinion on reason)

The obsolete RED part is a 630 nm deeper red but only 2000 lumen.

The new RED is 620 nm more amber red but is 3000 lumen.  Blue and green meanwhile are 5000 lumens and the low efficacy of red is common.

This datasheet is short on engineering reasons but has the usually marketing BS about mercury-free bulbs ( yet fails to mention the gallium arsenide content.)

So my opinion is perhaps what I might have done to alert field service people to the issue but hide the obvious reasons.

There is no damage to the reverse connection, but it won't work. and if replaced with the wrong colour, it won't work well either. So do two wrongs make it right?

The normal rated current in the forward mode is 27 Amps.

Comment: Great, thanks for this fast answer!
Just to be clear. I swap red and black cable and I also swap blue and black cable?

Comment: No need to change the thermistor wires, but you need a new ICC file from supplier